# getting crash in react native app for android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

in our react native app we have used firebase, and location services .

here we are getting crash in react native and its very difficult to understand and reproduce it.

here is the crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1285)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:458)
       at io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestoreTransactionHandler.safeUnlock(RNFirebaseFirestoreTransactionHandler.java:160)
       at io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestoreTransactionHandler.abort(RNFirebaseFirestoreTransactionHandler.java:50)
       at io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestore.transactionDispose(RNFirebaseFirestore.java:281)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

how to check the cause of this crash in react native ?

Comment: When does this crash happen ? When receiving a firebase notificaition ?

Comment: no, we are using firebase firestore database. in that we are using transactions, by seeing some of the lines. I can see its for transaction. But its difficult to reproduce that issue while debugging. we got this issues from fabric.

Comment: It looks like you also posted this on the github repo, with more details: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1178